# Scrapy crawl 301 redirect pages but doesn't scrape data from them

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

I can't figure out how to allow scrapy to scrape 301 redirected pages.
When I add

`handle_httpstatus_list = [301,302]`

the log stops telling me

`2015-09-29 09:45:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET http://www.example.com/conditions-generales/> (referer: http://www.example.com/)
2015-09-29 09:45:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <301 http://www.example.com/conditions-generales/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`

but only crawls 301 redirected pages and never scrapes data from them (while it does for 200 http status code pages).

I then get :

`2015-09-29 09:55:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (301) <GET http://www.example.com/espace-annonceurs/> (referer: http://www.example.com/)`

But never :

```
2015-09-29 09:55:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <301 http://www.example.com/espace-annonceurs/>
```

I would like to scrape http://www.example.com/espace-annonceurs/ juste the way I would if it were a 200 HTTP status code.

I suppose I have to use a middleware, but I don't know how to do this

Thank you for your help

Comment: "Scraped from" happens when you yield or return items in callbacks. If you don't get that log line, your callback(s) is not extracting any item from the 30x responses. Check what happens in your callback: for example, you can log every response URL with status code, and inspect what the HTTP 301 response body contain, if your scraping code works in all cases.

Comment: the callback function is the one called by the spider in the rules ? 
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(),process_links='fix_links', callback ='parse_url', follow=True)]

Comment: I'm sorry i'm quite new to scrapy and I don't really understand how it works
When "crawled" does happen ? Does that mean that the page is being visited by the spider ? Then why doesn't it just scrape data from the pages ? Does it depend on the http status code ? Where can I see that dependency ?

Comment: Indeed I logged the bodies of the responses that have 301 status code, and they are all empty...

I don't understand why

Comment: "crawled" happens at the downloader stage, before callback are called, it means that the page response has been downloaded. _why doesn't it just scrape data from the pages?_ it depends what your callback does regarding scraping data, does it handle the data in these 301 and 302 pages?
Make sure you also [disable RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:setting-REDIRECT_ENABLED).

Comment: HTTP 301 responses usually only have a "Location:" header with the URL to follow next, which [what RedirectMiddleware does](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/redirect.py#L69), so that you don't have to handle redirections. If you are not expecting an empty response body, and want to extract data from it, you'll have to dig why you are getting a different response from Scrapy. Without your spider and more info on the website, it's hard to help.

Comment: the website is www.financeutile.com which is also the starting url of my spider.

What the spider has to do on the pages of the website is quite simple : given a list of keywords (argument of the spider), it just looks at what keywords are on what page and how many times they are on the pages. The item has therefore just a 'keywords' argument, which is a dict with keywords as keys and count as values.

Comment: it also gets all the links lying in the visited pages and store them in a list (if these links point towards the same domain)